# Would canines that consume the stomach of ruminant prey animals benefit from any of the bacteria and enzymes present in the rumen?

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, microbiology, enzymes, nutrition

This question is inspired by the growth in popularity of raw diets for pet dogs. Green tripe is a common addition to these diets, with many claims of probiotic benefits.

Here's an example from a site that sells ground, frozen green tripe for pet dogs: http://greentripe.com/

Another article with some of the claimed benefits (I already know there is some misinformation in this article - it claims that dogs don't naturally produce the enzyme amylase, but that is false) http://ivcjournal.com/raw-green-tripe/

Do these claims make sense? I know most of the bacteria in the rumen would die after being exposed to oxygen, but would the rest of the bacteria, fungi, and enzymes present in the rumen be of any benefit to a canine when consumed?

What about after the tripe has been ground, frozen, etc?